# JavaScript function to identify URL and make them clickable

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement , my client send me a string. for the links he is sending link title in squre brackets and link with bracket. like below,

`[Google](https://www.google.com/)`

I need get that value and make it clickable [Google](https://www.google.com/) . adding like below and replace that to the original text.

`<a href = "' + title + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>'`

can anyone suggest better way of doing this with JavaScript regex.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) formatting, so you could use a markdown library like [Marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) to parse and render it:

```js
const s = '[Google](https://www.google.com/) ';

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = marked(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there is a limitation. i can't add any libraries at the moment. that is why i am looking it to JavaScript side. any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with String replace function.

Regex: `/\[(.*)\]\s*\((.*)\)/g`

Replacer: `<a href = "$2" target="_blank">$1</a>`

```js
const str = `Lorem ipsum. [Google](https://www.google.com/). Sample text.`

const output = replaceWithLinks(str);

console.log(output);

function replaceWithLinks(str) {
    return str.replace(/\[(.*)\]\s*\((.*)\)/g, '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$1</a>')
}
```

Comment: You can play around this here: https://regexr.com/66m6k

Answer (score 1):

In HTML file:

```
<h1 id="header"></h1>
```

In Js File:

```
const myString = "[Google](https://www.google.com/)";
const show = myString.match(/\[(.*?)\]/); // it return two things. The first is with bracket and the second one is without bracket you have to use without bracket.
const url = myString.match(/\((.*?)\)/);
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = `<a href="${url[1]}" target="_blank">${show[1]}</a>`;
```

You have to use regular expression. To get information about regular expression read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Get the first index value and show it to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is very handy for this purpose. just copy below code to F12 console for a preview

```
"text before [Google](https://www.google.com/) and after".replace(/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gm, '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$1</a>')
```

ps: the code copy from a [simple markdown parser](https://github.com/casualwriter/powerpage-md-document/blob/main/index.html)